# How to get feature importance in predicting something for every each year using different index?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have these two datasets, one of these is various index for long long period and the second one is the total number of typhoons for same period as the former one.

First dataset (dimension : (22, 30) )

```
            A  B   C    D   E    F  G   H   I  J  \
Unnamed: 0                                                                    
1979         1803.0  1.1  0.16 -0.15 -0.29 -0.24    -0.08  0.42  0.10 -0.81   
1980         1932.0 -0.0 -0.36  0.08  0.21  0.16     0.64  0.47 -0.08  1.21   
1981         1569.0  2.0 -0.63 -0.43 -0.46 -0.59    -0.47  0.18 -0.22 -0.80   
1982         1719.0 -1.7  0.13  0.54  0.53  0.45     1.74 -0.15 -0.45 -0.14   
1983         1386.0  0.1  4.24  1.52  0.54 -0.00     0.82  0.35 -0.45  4.82   
1984         1003.0 -0.6 -0.95 -1.17 -0.90 -0.78    -0.28 -0.37  0.46 -2.62   
1985          761.0 -0.6 -1.27 -1.02 -0.91 -0.95    -0.11 -0.30  0.04 -1.59
```

Second dataset (dimension : (30, ))

```
Unnamed: 0        
1979        0.68  
1980        0.45  
1981        0.20  
1982        1.14  
1983        1.38  
1984       -1.89  
1985        0.25  
1986       -0.17  
1987        0.58
```

I want to make ANN model which can predict the total number (like first dataset) for future while using various index (like second dataset), so I tried to make a model for it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# upload dataset
X = pd.read_csv('index.csv')
X.set_index('Unnamed: 0', inplace=True)
X = X.T
X = X.values

raw_data = pd.read_csv('sum.csv')
y = raw_data.iloc[30:60, -1]
y = y.values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

But I got an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-5f25f916c229> in <module>
     16 y = y.values
     17 
---> 18 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    332         raise ValueError(
    333             "Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: %r"
--> 334             % [int(l) for l in lengths]
    335         )
    336 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [22, 30]
```

How can I deal with this new ANN problem and more essential problem (dimension stuff)?

Comment: It's hard to follow the description of the datasets. Please describe it with more details. For example, what's the meaning of `dimension:(22,30)` for the first dataset and `dimension: (30, )` for the second dataset, what's the meaning of the data within the second dataset, and which column is the number of typhoons?

Comment: First dataset has 22 columns(including 22 climatological indice which are related to whole world's or certain area's climate) and 30 indice(all 30 indices mean each years from 1979 to 2008). It presents various indice's change or variation depending on areas.   And second one has only 30 indice which means same to first dataset's indice.(all years during same period). Its value indicates total typhoon numbers during 2 months for a given period(1979~2008)

Comment: you probably just don't need `X = X.T`, then they should both be of length 30

Comment: you such a genius, thanks!